# many to many and one to many relationship in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have three tables: "courriers" which is connected with "reponses" by one to-many relationship (1 courrier could have many reponses), and "structures" which is connected with "courriers" by many-to-many relationship
I want to find the courriers which are connected to a certain structure and doesn't have a reponse in table "reponses".
For example, for the structures "DMO" that has 1 as identifiant in "structures", I wish find the courriers that belongs to this structure and doesn't appear in "reponses".
Am using Laravel 8, I want to do this with Eloquent ORM.
Am trying this

```
           public function dmoDG()
           {   
            $structure = Structure::find(1);
            $cou = $structure->courriers;
            
            $courr = $cou->where('repondre','=',1)- 
             >where('dmo_sec','<>',NULL);

            $courriers = $courr->doesntHave('reponses')->get();
           
            return view("DG\dmoDG", compact('courriers'));
           }
```

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::doesntHave does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$model->relation`, it fetches all related records and returns them as a Collection.

If you want to use query builder on a relation, you need to use it as a method: `$model->relation()`

So, if you access your relation as a property, you got Collection.
But if you access your relation as a method, you got query builder and add your where clauses on it.

In your example;

```
public function dmoDG()
{
    $structure = Structure::find(1);
    // $cou = $structure->courriers; // for using without parentheses you got a collection, not a query builder

    $cou = $structure->courriers(); // now you will have a query builder and Where clauses will work on this

    $courr = $cou->where('repondre', '=', 1)->where('dmo_sec', '<>', NULL);

    $courriers = $courr->doesntHave('reponses')->get();

    return view("DG\dmoDG", compact('courriers'));
}
```

Actually you can pipe them to one liner:

```
public function dmoDG()
{
    $structure = Structure::find(1);
    
    $courriers = $structure->courriers()->where('repondre', '=', 1)->where('dmo_sec', '<>', NULL)->doesntHave('reponses')->get();

    return view("DG\dmoDG", compact('courriers'));
}
```

Make sure your relations and column names correctly specified.